# Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, connection

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database, with CakePHP 2.2.4. As my dev environment I have installed a fresh WAMP Server on my machine.

I have enabled the PHP extensions:

- php_mssql
- php_pdo_mssql
- php_sqlsrv_53_ts
- php_curl (this one might be irrelevant).

I also have enabled the module in Apache:

- rewrite_module.

I have have changed the salt entries in the core.php file. I have tried to connect to my database through database.php as so:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'Servername',
    'login' => 'Username',
    'password' => 'secretpassword',
    'database' => 'TheDatabase',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

I go to the index.php to test the connection and i get in yellow:

> > Cake is NOT able to connect to the database. Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created.

I see that it is failing at the `datasource` so it must be some module or extension or dll or something missing ... 
The server is located within our intranet, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The DataSource is defined in the file  lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Sqlserver.php

> Requires the `sqlsrv`  * and `pdo_sqlsrv` extensions to be enabled."

Check phpinfo() to see if the extensions are enabled.